# Implement Gantt Highcharts in react

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

Hi I'm new to both the techs anyone can help with the implementation of gantt chart higharts in react .

Hi have tried the basic of react and made a file with the following compenents.
import './App.css';
import GanttMainDiv from './Components/GanttMainDiv';

function App() {
return (

```
<div className="App">
  <script src="//cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
  <div id="chartdiv"></div>
  <GanttMainDiv />
</div>
```

);
}

export default App;

Can someone help me with implementation ,events and manipulation .

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you want to use the Highcharts library? From the part of the code that you shared looks like you are trying to use amcharts.

Anyway, here is a basic demo of the Highcharts Gantt implemented in the React environment: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-vcs5b?file=/demo.jsx

Comment: Yes the i tried with amcharts but the requirement is with the highcharts

Comment: Can u please share the implementation details or steps for the same

Comment: Have you already got known with the documentation? https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react